# Non-homogeneous JSON data return from backend server

Tags: android, json, okhttp

My Android application is simply, companies push out jobs out to workers and workers accepts or decline the job offer. Here is my flow, whenever a job has been accepts on the worker's phone, I re-fetch the job offers to update the screen and the JSON is an homogeneous array structure.

So I ran into this bug where If I have jobs from two companies, say 2 jobs from Company A and 1 job from Company B, if I accept the job offered by companies B, since it is the last company B job on the list, the response data type is non-homogeneous. Please see below for the before and after JSON return

[image]

The picture tagged with the BEFORE is the when I have 2 company A jobs and 1 company B job. Upon accepting the 1 company B job and re-fetch the job requests, I get the JSON response in the AFTER picture. Although it is a valid JSON return, however because of the comma in the front of the array makes the JSON structure a completely different structure to the BEFORE picture, the only way around it would be to anticipate the "2 company A, 1 company B" scenario and create a new POJO to parse this return, is there a better way to work around it?

Should this issue be rectified on the client side (mobile) or the server side (Backend)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be solved on the backend. You are currently returning an array of "job" objects, why would this array suddenly include a string!?

If you absolutely have to return something, an empty object (or the previous object with something like `"valid":false`) makes more sense than a string.

Alternatively (and not very cleanly) you could parse the array, then check if each object is your job object, ending up with a new array of just your desired type.